# How to exit app from login while logout from the app using navigation component?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Below is my code;

**navigation.xml**

```
 <fragment android:id="@+id/HomeFragment"
          android:label="Home Screen">
    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_activeRefillDeviceFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</fragment>

  <fragment android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
          android:name="com.example.dprefilldevice.login.fragment.LoginFragment"
          android:label="LoginFragment">
    <action android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_activeRefillDeviceFragment"
            app:destination="@id/activeRefillDeviceFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</fragment>
```

Logout button click event;

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.logout -> {
            Utils.getPreferrence(context)?.edit()?.clear()?.apply()
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_activeRefillDeviceFragment_to_loginFragment)
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Comment: Call `finish()` on the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try to make change to your graph: change first action to have `app:popUpTo="@id/HomeFragment"`. Idea behind this: to remove home fragment from backstack and then place login fragment into backstack. I do not recommend to forcibly finish your activity.